Rasa form is unexpectedly halting midway and predicting a fallback action without completing the entire form
stories.yml
version: "3.1"

stories:

- story: form fill
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: basic_form  
  - active_loop: basic_form

rules.yml
version: "3.1"

rules:

- rule: activate form loop
  steps:
  - intent: greet
  - action: basic_form
  - active_loop: basic_form

- rule: Intruption in form
  condition:
  - active_loop: basic_form
  steps:
  - intent: general_chat
  - action: action_general_chat
  - action: basic_form
  - active_loop: basic_form

nlu.yml
version: "3.1"

nlu:
  - intent: greet
    examples: |
      - Hi
      - Hello
      - Hey
  - intent: affirm
    examples: |
      - yes
      - y
      - indeed
      - of course
      - that sounds good
      - correct
      - /affirm
  - intent: deny
    examples: |
      - no
      - n
      - never
      - I don't think so
      - don't like that
      - no way
      - not really
  - intent: provide_name
    examples: |
      - My name is [John](first_name)
      - I'm [Alice](first_name)
      - You can call me [Michael](first_name)
      - [rutvi](first_name)
      - [John](first_name)
      - [Emma](first_name)
      - [Michael](first_name)
      - [Sophia](first_name)
      - [William](first_name)
      - [Alice](middle_name) [Jane](middle_name)
      - [Robert](middle_name) [Lee](middle_name)
      - [Elizabeth](middle_name) [Ann](middle_name)
      - [David](middle_name) [Michael](middle_name)
      - [Olivia](middle_name) [Grace](middle_name)
      - [Smith](last_name)
      - [Johnson](last_name)
      - [Williams](last_name)
      - [Jones](last_name)
      - [Brown](last_name)
  - intent: provide_email
    examples: |
      - [john.doe@example.com](email)
      - [emma.smith@company.org](email)
      - [michael.johnson@email.net](email)
      - [sophia.williams@business.com](email)
      - [william.jones@university.edu](email)
  - intent: provide_phone
    examples: |
      - [(555) 123-4567](phone)
      - [(650) 987-6543](phone)
      - [(212) 456-7890](phone)
      - [(415) 234-5678](phone)
      - [(305) 567-8901](phone)
      - [9876543210](phone)
      - [1234567890](phone)
      - [5678901234](phone)
      - [7890123456](phone)
      - [2345678901](phone)
  - intent: goodbye
    examples: |
      - goodbye
      - bye
      - see you later
      - I'm done
      - exit
      - all done
      - thank you

domain.yml
version: "3.1"

intents:
  - greet
  - provide_name
  - provide_email
  - goodbye
  - bot_challenge
  - affirm
  - deny
  - restart_conversation
  - general_chat
  - provide_phone
  - become_citizen


entities:
  - first_name  
  - middle_name  
  - last_name 
  - email
  - us_number
  - phone
  - confirm_location
  - confirm_mail_address

slots:
  first_name:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: first_name
  middle_name:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: middle_name
  last_name:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: last_name
  email:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: email
  us_number:
    type: bool
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_intent
      value: true
      intent: affirm
    - type: from_intent
      value: false
      intent: deny
  phone:
    type: text
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_entity
      entity: phone
      action: action_check_required_slots_for_form
  confirm_location:
    type: bool
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_intent
      value: true
      intent: affirm
    - type: from_intent
      value: false
      intent: deny
  confirm_mail_address:
    type: bool
    influence_conversation: true
    mappings:
    - type: from_intent
      value: true
      intent: affirm
    - type: from_intent
      value: false
      intent: deny

forms: 
  basic_form:
    required_slots:
      - first_name
      - middle_name
      - last_name
      - email
      - us_number
      - phone
      - confirm_location
      - confirm_mail_address
      
responses:
  utter_ask_first_name:
  - text: "What is your first name ?"

  utter_ask_middle_name:
  - text: "What is your middle name ?"

  utter_ask_last_name:
  - text: "What is your last name ?"

  utter_ask_email:
  - text: "What is your email ?"

  utter_ask_us_number:  
    - text: "Do you have the U.S. Phone Number ?"
      buttons:
        - title: yes
          payload: "/affirm"
        - title: no
          payload: "/deny"
  
  utter_ask_phone:
  - text: "Provide me your phone number"

  utter_ask_confirm_location:  
    - text: "Just to confirm: do you live at this address ?"
      buttons:
        - title: yes
          payload: "/affirm"
        - title: no
          payload: "/deny"
  
  utter_ask_confirm_mail_address:  
    - text: "Would you like to receive mail related to this application at this address ?"
      buttons:
        - title: yes
          payload: "/affirm"
        - title: no
          payload: "/deny"

  utter_iamabot:
  - text: I am a bot, powered by Rasa.

  utter_goodbye:
  - text: Bye

session_config:
  carry_over_slots_to_new_session: true

actions:
  - action_general_chat
  - action_check_required_slots_for_form


config.yml

recipe: default.v1


assistant_id: 20240508-161019-amortized-belvedere

language: en

pipeline: null

policies: 
  - name: RulePolicy
  

credentials.yml


rest:

rasa:
  url: "http://localhost:5002/api"


I am using Rasa Version: 3.6.20
I want that rasa form should ask fix 40 questions in sequence in between there can be multiple yes or no questions ( if yes then different question ) , but while asking phone number it get stuck on that point and will no longer ask next question
While debugging it further by running rasa shell --debug it is automatically predicting fallback action in middle to basic form loop and empty all the slot values I dont know why so I need to fix this and want that bot will ask 40 50 questions in sequence as I provide




Create a custom action for fallback without sending a message:
Python
from rasa_sdk import Action, Tracker
from rasa_sdk.executor import CollectingDispatcher
from rasa_sdk.events import UserUtteranceReverted
class ActionSilentFallback(Action):
def name(self) -> str:
return "action_silent_fallback"
async def run(self, dispatcher: CollectingDispatcher,
              tracker: Tracker,
              domain: dict) -> list:
    # Revert user's last input without sending message
    return [UserUtteranceReverted()]

AI-generated code. Please review and use carefully. More information about the FAQ.
Update the domain file (domain.yml) to include the new fallback action:
actions:

action_silent_fallback

Configure the fallback policy in the configuration file (config.yml):
policies:

name: RulePolicy
core_fallback_action_name: "action_silent_fallback"
core_fallback_threshold: 0.4

Add a rule for the fallback action in the rules file (rules.yml):
rules:

rule: Fallback
steps:

intent: nlu_fallback
action: action_silent_fallback



With this configuration, the fallback action will be triggered without sending a message to the user, and previously filled slots will not be cleared. If it still doesn't work, you may need to check if there are other policies or settings that could be interfering.
